# IIF having errors on SSRS Textbox

Tags: reporting-services

`=IIF(Fields!CODE_VALUE.Value="A" AND Fields!CHECKED.Value=1), "ü","")`

Error says this

`The Value expression for the textrun 'ID.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' contains an error: [BC30516] Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'IIf' accepts this number of arguments.`

Comment: mismatch in brackets.. you have 2 closing ) brackets but only one after the IIF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra bracket in your statment:

=IIF(Fields!CODE_VALUE.Value="A" AND Fields!CHECKED.Value=1, "ü","")